# How to get only one field per line from CSV file on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a CSV file that has many lines and I want to extract only one column out of it.

Here is the data example, one line of CSV file.

3161;ineedthis;2676;Y;;;;;text;;;text;;;hello;world;

I need to extract only second word of this line and add it to array.

I have already managed to get the CSV file to NSString, there is only question of parsing it now.

I have tried components of string method, but it returns full line and not the part I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *list = @"3161;ineedthis;...";
NSString *str = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@";"][1];
```

Comment: Make use of the same code but with whatever separator is being used for the file. This will probably be `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]`

Comment: This code only works if there are no semicolons in the field values.

Comment: @rmaddy: would seem silly to use a delimiter which is a valid character in a field value.

Comment: Not at all. What if I wanted the value ";,:|\t" (where \t is really a tab)? I'm just pointing out a potential issue. Parsing general CSV is far more complex than most people realize.